# Does Firebase create a topic when I subscribe to a non existing one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

I started working with Firebase in order to simplify the use of Push Notifications of my app. Searching around the Docs I found the possibility to send a notification to a group of devices through a topic which the devices are subscribed to.
My doubt comes out here. When I subscribe the devices (using firebaseToken) to the topic I want to use, does this topic creates implicitly if it's not created?
If it doesn't, when and how can I create a topic to use it later?
I'm using Firebase Cloud Store an Firebase Messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a topic in order to use topic messaging.  It just works the way you expect as long as the server and clients all agree on the name of the topic.

Firebase Cloud Messaging isn't related to Cloud Firestore in any way, other than that they are both Firebase products and are seen together in documentation and the console.

Comment: Okay thank you!
But I don't know about he second part, I'm using Cloud Firestore so that way I can create listeners on it and send notifications basing on the changes of the Cloud Firestore, so it's all related in my case! haha

Comment: The products are not really related. The operation of messaging doesn't affect the operation of the database. You can use them separately or together, it doesn't matter.